# Kotlin way in conditional flows

Tags: kotlin

What would be the best kotlin way to have the following logic?

```
      if (it.records.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (it.records[0].fields.isNotEmpty()) {
          if (it.records[0].fields["lastModifiedDate"] != null) {
            RECORD_DATA_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_FORMAT.parse(
                it.records[0].fields["lastModifiedDate"])
          } else {
            Date(0)
          }
        } else {
          Date(0)
        }
      } else {
        Date(0)
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide all the code necessary to run your code I decided to create 2 classes and a function

```
data class Musician(
    val records: List<Record>
)

data class Record(
    val fields: Map<String, String>
)

fun test(mus: Musician): Date { }
```

Only by using the elvis operator and some common syntax you could get something like this:

```
fun test(mus: Musician): Date {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

    return if(mus.records.isNotEmpty() && 
mus.records[0].fields.isNotEmpty())
        sdf.parse(mus.records[0].fields["lastModifiedDate"]) ?: Date(0)
    else
        Date(0)
}
```

And if you want to use even more Kotlin fun stuff you could create somethig like:

```
fun test(mus: Musician): Date {
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

    return mus.records.firstOrNull()?.fields?.get("lasModifiedDate")?.let { 
        sdf.parse(it) 
    } ?: Date(0)
}
```

This is probably not the best way to handle this situation, but these are some options of what you can do with Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some detail, but probably something like this:

```
val date = it.records[0]?.fields["lastModifiedDate"]?.let { RECORD_DATA_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE.parse(it)} ?: Date(0)
```

Comment: records[0] is causing a crash when records is empty, so I had to go with  records.firstOrNull()?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.